# Vlookup max / min of multiple results

Tags: arrays, excel, excel-formula, powerquery

I have a list of values in EXCEL

```
X   Y
5   3000
5   3200
5   2800
10  1600
10  2900
10  3500
15  1800
15  4500
```

I want to get the list of X without duplicates and corresponding MIN / MAX values Y. Something like this for MAX values:

```
X   Y
5   3200
10  3500
15  4500
```

How do I proceed?

Answer (score 1):

A simple pivot table will do that.

- Insert Pivot Table
- Drag X to the rows area
- Drag y to the Values area twice

  - Adjust value settings for one Y  to MAX
  - Adjust value settings for one Y  to MIN

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [`PowerQuery`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/connect-to-an-excel-table-or-range-power-query-67538004-cd12-4b61-9cee-8720db1c7136):

- Select any cell within your data range.
- Click the `Data` tab, then > `From Table/Range`.
- If prompted, in the `From Table` dialog box, you can click the `Range Selection` button to select a specific range to use as a data source.
- If the table or range of data has column headers, you can check `My table has headers`. The header cells are used to define the column names for the query.

Within `PowerQuery` AKA `Get&TransForm`

- Click the `Transform` tab, then > `Group by`.
- In the dialog box, click `Advanced` and under `Group by` you choose `X`
- Choose a `New column name`, e.g.: `maxVals`. Furthermore choose `Max` as an `Operation` and under `Column` you choose `Y`.
- Confirm through `OK` and close `PowerQuery`.

You'll now end up with your desired output. Replicate this for the `minVals`.

Answer (score 0):

For MAX values you could sort your data: column X ascending & column Y descending and then apply an advanced filter (only to column X), checking the option for unique values only for MIN values you repeat the process but specify ascending as the sort order for column Y
Recording macros of these actions will provide you with the VBA code, which you should be able to make dynamic as you are asking your question in a Lecture after the Sections on Variables and Range References.

I hope this will be helpful